Are there any mechanical implications of the laws imposed by the gods of magic in Dragonlance setting?
During the Second Dragon War, three elven mages unleashed the incommensurable and deep magic power of Krynn for fighting dragons and their armies. This led to victory, but also to immense destruction to Silvanesti and to Krynn itself.
Therefore, for the love of magic itself, the three gods Solinari, Lunitari and Nuitari taught to the three wizards how to control the magical power of the world. The wizards hence founded the Orders of High Sorcery, setting rigid laws for avoiding the endangering of Krynn when casting spells and using magic.
Beside the in-world rigid laws (the three orders-White, Red and Black Robes-, the Test of High Sorcery, renegades mages,...), are there any mechanical implications in the rules in any edition?
For comparison, in the Forgotten Realms setting, Karsus' folly led to the death of the first goddess of magic, Mystryl, and the reincarnated Mystra banned spells above the 10th level1.

1According to this list, the sole 10th level spell was Create Mythal, which has been banned too. The 3rd edition introduced then Epic Slots and Epic Spells, that are considered 10th level spells.
